# MySQL: Join on same table with sorting

Tags: mysql, join

I am performing  a join on a same table t(type_id,place_name) on different type_id :

```
------------------
type_id|place_name
-------|----------
  1    |    A
  1    |    B
  2    |    X
  2    |    Y
------------------
```

My query is :

```
select t1.type_id, t1.place_name
from t as t1
join t as t2
on  
    t1.type_id!= t2.type_id AND
    t1.place_name!=t2.place_name;
```

I get result:

```
-------------------
type_id|place_name
-------|-----------
   2   |    X
   2   |    Y
   2   |    X
   2   |    Y
   1   |    A
   1   |    B
   1   |    A
   1   |    B
 -------------------
```

But I want result like:

```
-------------------
type_id|place_name
-------|-----------
   1   |    A
   2   |    X
   1   |    A
   2   |    Y
   1   |    B
   2   |    X
   1   |    B
   2   |    Y
 -------------------
```

I need to sort the result using order by. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit bro @AlexTartan

Comment: What logic do you use to order the rows?

Comment: `... order by place_name, type_id`

Comment: not using any order by here. I used order by type_id earlier.but not getting what I need.@Eric

Comment: But what order DO you need? If you say '1, 2, 3, 4', we all understand. If you say 'ABXY' we will probably understand too. But I don't see any logic in the order in your example.

Comment: not getting intended result@MichaelO.

Comment: I can use use order by type_id,which will sort like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2..but I want to sort like 1,2,1,2,1,2....@PetervanderWal

Comment: It is not possible with the current data: There is no way for MySQL to see the relation between your 1 and 2 type_id with the place_name. Every record with (1,A) is the same. So to do this you will have to add an extra column which has to result in an unique sort-able id (again: Your data sample does not provide that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want kind of a zipped order, it could be something like this:

```
select t1.type_id, t1.place_name
from t as t1
join t as t2
on  
    t1.type_id!= t2.type_id AND
    t1.place_name!=t2.place_name
order by
  least(t1.place_name, t2.place_name),
  greatest(t1.place_name, t2.place_name),
  t1.type_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f25743/2)

Since you can't explain exactly the logic of the order, I can't tell you if it will work well for other data. Instead of `place_name` you might need to use a combination of both columns.